# gmail bot seems to be sending out emails when configured in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, bots

I volunteer at a Nonprofit organization. We have an Exchange Server using Outlook. One of the employees linked her work email with her Gmail account. Last week, she called me to look at her mail. She was getting bounce backs from her sending emails out at about one every two seconds. Her Gmail account would send out an email and the not delivered would come back. We sent the PC out to a technician and he said the PC was clean. Well, I reconfigured her workstation for Outlook and within six seconds the emails started to produce again. I am going to recover you PC with our Dell disks, but I am afraid no matter what I do to her PC, when I configure for Outlook it will just start the bot from Gmail again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is nothing wrong with her PC. When a spam message goes out, they can set the From address to anything they want and the bouncebacks will be sent to your user. This is sometimes known as [Backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28email%29) Spam.

That said, she should change her passwords on both the Exchange account and the Gmail account.